# need help undestanding iterator implementation

Tags: java, iterator

I'm having trouble understanding an assignment I was given in class, the description reads:

Create three public queue classes calles QueueExtendingVect and QueueContaingVect. The first should implement a queue using the Vector class by extending it, and implementing iterators of type Iterator; and the second should implement a queue using the Vector class by containing a Vector object and of course implementing iterators of type Iterator. Each of the classes should implement the iterator() instance method to create an Iterator instance. Implement remove() in Iterator by simply throwing a java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException when called. Note that Iterator.next() returns reference to the actual client object stored and advances the iterator.

by extending vector, I can create an instance of Iterator and use it to iterate through the vector, and use the .next() and remove() methods.

here is my code so far...

```
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.NoSuchElementException;
import java.util.Vector;

@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
public class QueueExtendingVector extends Vector  implements Cloneable, Iterable{

/** no-args constructor*/       
    public QueueExtendingVector() { 

    }   

    public void remove(){
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }


/** adds element to end of Queue takes Object as arguement, calls addElement()*/    
    public void enqueue (Object c){
        this.addElement(c); 
    }   
/** dequeue() removes first element of the Queue
 * @return */   
    public Object dequeue(){

    if (this.size() !=0){
        Object deleted =  this.elementAt(0);
            this.removeElementAt(0);
            return deleted;
        }
    else{
    return -1;
    }

    }
/** empty() returns true if Queue is empty*/    
    public boolean empty(){
        return this.isEmpty();  
    }   
/** makeNull sets all elements of Queue to null*/
    public void makeNull(){

        int s = this.size();   // number of elements not capacity
        //System.out.println(s);
        for ( int i = 0 ; i < s ; i++){
            this.set(i, null);
        }       
    }

/** equals() checks quality of two QEV object references, returns true if  references point to same object and true if objects referred to are equal*/
    public boolean equals(Object o ){   

        if( this == o ){  // if pointing at same object return true
            return true;
        }
        if(!(o instanceof QueueExtendingVector)){ // if o not an instance of QEV return false
            return false;
        }

        int mySize = this.size(); // size of this QEV
        int compareToSize = ((QueueExtendingVector)o).size(); // size of object comparing to

        if(mySize != compareToSize){ // if the sizes (number of elements) are not same returns false;
            System.out.println("Sizes Unequal");
            return false;
        }               
        for ( int i = 0 ; i < mySize; i++ ) // loop through QEV
            if(  ((QueueExtendingVector)o).elementAt(i).equals(this.elementAt(i))){ // if equal (true) continue looping         
            }
            else { // if not equal, break from loop return false
                return false;               
        }   
        return true; // after loop finishes returns true
}
/** toString() method returns String*/
    public String toString(){       

        String s = "";

        for ( int i = 0 ; i < this.size(); i++){
            s+= this.elementAt(i).toString() + " , ";           
        }
        return s;
    }
/** front() returns first element of Queue*/    
    public Object front(){ 
        return this.firstElement();
    }

    public Object clone(){
        Object o = null;
        Object q = new QueueExtendingVector();  

        for(int i = 0 ; i < this.size(); i++){          

            try {               
                o =  this.get(i).getClass().getMethod("clone", null).invoke(this.get(i), null);
                ((QueueExtendingVector)q).add(o);               
            } 
        //  catch (Throwable e){
            //}
            catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
                System.out.println("element at index " + i + ": [" + this.get(i).getClass() + "]is not cloneable, shallow copy only preformed");
                 Object t = this.elementAt(i);               
                ((QueueExtendingVector)q).add(t); // was add o
                //throw new Error(this.elementAt(i).getClass() + " must implement Cloneable");
                //e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
                //e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (SecurityException e) {
                //e.printStackTrace();
            }                                   
        }
        return q;

    }

in a class called A1, which we were given, and to use exactly as was such.

import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Vector;


public class A1 {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        QueueExtendingVector qev1 = new QueueExtendingVector();
        QueueExtendingVector qev2 = new QueueExtendingVector();
        QueueExtendingVector qev3;


        QueueContainingVector qcv1 = new QueueContainingVector();
        QueueContainingVector qcv2 = new QueueContainingVector();
        QueueContainingVector qcv3;

        CInteger ci = new CInteger(88);

        qev1.enqueue(ci);
        qev2.enqueue(ci);
        qcv1.enqueue(ci);
        qcv2.enqueue(ci);

        for ( int i = 0 ; i < 5; i++)
            if ( i%2 == 0){
                qev1.enqueue(new CInteger(i+1));
                qev2.enqueue(new CInteger(i+1));
                qcv1.enqueue(new CInteger(i+1));
                qcv2.enqueue(new CInteger(i+1));
            }
            else{
                qev1.enqueue(new Date(i*i));
                qev2.enqueue(new Date(i*i));
                qcv1.enqueue(new Date(i*i));
                qcv2.enqueue(new Date(i*i));

            }


// QueueExtendingVector ******************************************************************************************************


    if (qev1.equals(qev2)){     
        System.out.println("qev1.equals(qev2) is true");
    }
    else{
        System.out.println("qev1.equals(qev2) is false");
        }

    System.out.println("but........");
    if (qev1 == qev2){
    System.out.println("qev1 == qev2");
        }
    else{
    System.out.println("qev != qev2");
        }

    if(qev1.empty()){
        System.out.println("qev1 empty");
        }
    else{
        System.out.println("qev1 not empty");
        }

    qev3 = (QueueExtendingVector)qev1.clone();

    ci.seti(44);

    System.out.println("first element of qev1 is " + qev1.front());

    System.out.println("qev3 stringified(hopefully didn't change) = " + qev3);

    System.out.println("First elt of qev1 is: " + qev1.front());

    System.out.println(qev1.size());



    // ********** that first Iteratorstuff goes here!


    try{
    qev1.iterator().remove();

        }
    catch (UnsupportedOperationException e){
    System.out.println("Calling Iterator.remove() and throwing Exception");
        }

    Iterator i = qev1.iterator();
    for ( int j = 0 ; i.hasNext(); j ++){

    System.out.println("qev1[" + j + "] = " + i.next());
        }


    }

    }





}
```

what i dont understand is the lines:

```
try{
    qev1.iterator().remove();

        }
catch (UnsupportedOperationException e){
        System.out.println("Calling Iterator.remove() and throwing Exception");
        }

i get the illegal state exception which is thrown when , .next() is not called before .remove() is called
```

I dont understand how qev1.iterator().remove() could work?
do i need to override the iterator methods?

oracle docs states that:
IllegalStateException - if the next method has not yet been called, or the remove method has already been called after the last call to the next method

Answer (score 0):

You have to call `next()` method before calling `remove()` method to update the the index of the last returned element as shown below.

#### Look at the source code & comments of [AbstractList](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/AbstractList.java#AbstractList.Itr)

```
private class Itr implements Iterator<E> {
    /**
     * Index of element to be returned by subsequent call to next.
     */
    int cursor = 0;

    /**
     * Index of element returned by most recent call to next or
     * previous.  Reset to -1 if this element is deleted by a call
     * to remove.
     */
    int lastRet = -1;

    public E next() {
        ...
        int i = cursor;
        E next = get(i);
        lastRet = i;
        cursor = i + 1;               
        ...
    }

    public void remove() {
        if (lastRet < 0)
            throw new IllegalStateException();
        ...
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Each of the classes should implement the iterator() instance method to create an Iterator instance
```

It's in your question. Yes, you have to override the default implementation of the `iterator` method, and by the sound of it create your own iterator class.

Comment: ok , thats kinda what I came to, what made it absolutely more confusing is when I asked my professor , and he said , that I would only need to override the remove method, but not the next, or hasnext.......   so It sounds like I will need to write an inner Iterator class , and override the methods